# pywinauto batch file running error

Tags: python-2.7, pywinauto

Im a biologist and new to pywinauto, i wrote a code to open an input file in HYPHY application using pywinauto, when i run my code line by line in command line it works fine but when i run the code as a batch file it gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Masyh\Desktop\autowin_test.py", line 8, in <module>
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u' Please select a batch file to run:',   class_name='#32770')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

the code is:

```
import pywinauto

pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'HYPHY Console', class_name='HYPHY')[0]
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
window.SetFocus()
window.MenuItem(u'&File->&Open->Open &Batch File\tCtrl+O').Click()
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u' Please select a batch file to run:',        class_name='#32770')[0]
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
window.SetFocus()

ctrl = window['Edit']
ctrl.Click()
ctrl.TypeKeys('brown.nuc')
ctrl=window['&open']
ctrl.Click()
```

i guess the problem is that the window which gets the input(#'please select a batch file menue')  is not open at the beginning and the first part of the code opens it but python  looks for it from the beginning and cant find it.
i really appreciate any suggestions how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the window does not exist when the checking is performed. You should wait for a some time for window is opened.
try the next construction:

```
a_check = lambda: pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u' Please select a batch file to run:',        class_name='#32770')[0]
try:
    w_handle = pywinauto.timings.WaitUntilPasses(timeout=10, retry_interval=1, a_check)
except:
    print('Something went wrong')
```

Also, your problem can be caused by the window has extra attributes/state. For example, inisible.
Use allowed argumens from find_windows to handle such cases, here the arguments list with defaul values:

```
pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(class_name=None,class_name_re=None, parent=None, process=None, title=None, title_re=None, top_level_only=True, visible_only=True, enabled_only=False, best_match=None, handle=None, ctrl_index=None, predicate_func=None, active_only=False, control_id=None)
```